# Filling Forms and Downloading Files - Requests and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, download

I'm trying to scrap [these page](http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp). I used requests library to fill the forms. These part is working because when I change to holidays dates or not a dd/mm/yyyy format in the Dt_Ref form, I am warned.

The objective is to download the results of the filled form.

1 - Fill the Forms
2 - Download the file that is generated

Here's the code.

*Ps, I'm working under a corporate proxy, so I used HTTPProxyAuth to login with my credentials.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth


params = {'Dt_Ref': '20/08/2017', 'TpInstFinanceiro': 'Debentures'}

company_proxy = {"http":"proxy.xxxxx/yyyyyy.pac"}
credenciais = HTTPProxyAuth("qqqqq", "wwwww")

url = 'http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune_down.asp'


r = requests.post(url, data = params, proxies = itau_proxy , auth = credenciais)
```

Any idea about how to download the file?

Comment: Did you get correct response? check response data in `print(r.text)`. Is that what you want to get?

Comment: No. That will return the page, which will be in blank. When I fell the forms of [these page](http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp), I'm redirected to [these page](http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune_down.asp) which starts a download. The download file is what matters to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed some important parameters in the post data. Try with this `params` dictionary:

```
params = {
    'TpInstFinanceiro':'DEB', 'Tipo':'1', 
    'Dt_Ref':'02/08/2017', 'saida':'csv'
}
```

If will you don't want a csv file you can change the `params['saida']` value.

Comment: Sure. But how I will download this file? That is the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: You can get the csv file with `r.content`.

Comment: After inserting these parameters, the code worked. Thank you.